Can we move an answer into another question without merging?
This question

Verify partial message given hash of full message

has two answers and the reason is simple, the OP was not clear about their O(1) requirement, see the update, mentioned it around one day later.
After the OP was clear about their real intention,  Squeamish, instead of deleting the old answer, provide another one.
However, the first answer got the first down-vote since it was not answering to the question ( indicated by the down voter)
Both questions are valid and both have valid answers, however, the system shows only the last one.
If we can create a new question of the old version of the original question then move the old answer there without losing the points, it will be a nice solution. Can we do?


If we can create a new question of the old version of the original question then move the old answer there without losing the points, it will be a nice solution. Can we do?

No, at least moderators can't.
People with developer access probably can, perhaps Community Managers as well.
I checked my tools and for moderators the only way to move answers with their score is merging and / or migrating.

Should we request one?

@kelalaka Such a tool should be requested on [meta.se] (though I'm not overly confident it has many interesting uses), for the specific case here I also don't see a strong need for such intervention. If you want to, you can of course ask the new question and make a community wiki answer quoting Squeamish's.

you mean ask a new question then copy and paste the answer than quote and ask people to go and vote for the real answer at the beginning of the community asnwer? Then I'll try that later.
